# Database field definitions

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to do a data migration from a data base and I'm not too familiar with databases so I would like some clarification. I have some documentation that could apply to either an Oracle or a SQL database and it has a column defined as NUMBER(10,5). I would like to know what this means. I think it means that the number has 10 digits with 5 after the decimal point, but I would like clarification. Also would this be different for either SQL or Oracle?

Comment: If you are doing a data migration and you don't even know basic datatypes you are in over your head. This is NOT a task a beginner should even attempt. You need advanced skills for this and you don't even have basic ones.

Comment: Technically I'm not doing it. But one of my coworkers was debugging and issue in a data migration ask for my opinion and both of us were unsure if we were interpreting the documentation correctly or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first number is precision the second number is scale.  The equivalent in SQL Server can be as Decimal / Numeric and you could define it like so:

```
DECLARE @MyDec decimal(18,2)
```

The 18 is the max total number of decimal digits that can be stored **(that is the total number of digits, for instance 123.45 the precision here is 5, while the scale is 2)**.  The 2 is the scale and it specifies the max number of digits stored to the right of the decimal point.

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258832(v=SQL.80).aspx)

Just remember the more precision the more size in storage bytes.  So keep it at a minimum if possible.

> p (precision)
>
> Specifies the maximum total number of
>   decimal digits that can be stored,
>   both to the left and to the right of
>   the decimal point. The precision must
>   be a value from 1 through the maximum
>   precision. The maximum precision is
>   38. The default precision is 18.
>
> s (scale)
>
> Specifies the maximum number of
>   decimal digits that can be stored to
>   the right of the decimal point. Scale
>   must be a value from 0 through p.
>   Scale can be specified only if
>   precision is specified. The default
>   scale is 0; therefore, 0 <= s <= p.
>   Maximum storage sizes vary, based on
>   the precision.

Finally, it is worth mentioning that in oracle you can define a scale greater then a precision, for instance Number(3, 10) is valid in oracle.  SQL Server on the other hand requires that the precision >= scale.  So if you defined Number(3,10) in oracle, it would map into sql as Number(10,10).

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, a column defined as NUMBER(4,5) requires a zero for the first digit after the decimal point and rounds all values past the fifth digit after the decimal point.

From the [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96540/sql_elements2a.htm)

```
NUMBER(p,s)
```

> where: p is the precision, or the
>   total number of digits. Oracle
>   guarantees the portability of numbers
>   with precision ranging from 1 to 38. s
>   is the scale, or the number of digits
>   to the right of the decimal point. The
>   scale can range from -84 to 127.

Here are some examples :

Actual data `.000127` stored in `NUMBER(4,5)` becomes `.00013`

Actual data `7456123.89` stored in `NUMBER(7,-2)` becomes `7456100`

**Edited**

JonH mentions something noteworthy:

> Oracle allows the scale > precision,
>   so SQL will map that so that if s>p
>   then p becomes s. That is NUMBER(3, 4)
>   in oracle becomes NUMERIC(4,4) in SQL.

Comment: Also SQL does not support the scale to be greater then the precision. The op asked for both support. Oracle allows the scale > precision, so SQL will map that so that if s>p then p becomes s. That is NUMBER(3, 4) in oracle becomes NUMERIC(4,4) in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Defining a column in Oracle as NUMBER(10,5) means that the column value can have a decimal of up to five places of precision, and ten digits in overall length.  If you insert a value into the column that does not have any decimal places defined, the maximum the column will support is 10 digits.  For example, these values will be supported by the column defined as NUMBER(10,5):

```
1234567890
 12345.67890
```

It made validation a pain.

MySQL and SQL Server don't support the NUMBER data type - to support decimals, you're looking at using DECIMAL (or FLOAT?).  I haven't looked at PostgreSQL, but I would figure it to be similar to Oracle.

Comment: DECIMAL / NUMERIC are equivalents and both supported by SQL Server.  Floats in sql server maps to real in oracle.

Comment: And never use float if  you need to perform calculations!

Comment: @JonH: `NUMERIC` != `NUMBER`; the functionality is similar, but the keyword isn't.  Sounds like splitting hairs, but it will mean that you can't port scripts from one to the other without intervention.

Comment: Sorry I meant NUMBER not numeric.

Comment: @JonH: SQL Server only has a [NUMERIC data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx), there's no NUMBER.  [Likewise for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

Comment: @OMG Ponies I understand that, I never said it was I said Decimal / Numeric.  NUMBER was in reference to oracle.